# Items in carousel not clickab/selectable on smart-display

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I am using Dialogflow and actions on Google to talk to my smart display (Google Nest Hub). In one of my intents I show a carousel. I can browse the carousel and call the next intent correctly via voice command, however I cannot touch or click on any of the items shown in my carousel. Yet, when I test my app in Dialogflow or the Actions Console test-area, it works (I can click on items and thereby trigger the next intent). Is there something special in the payload I need to look at to make the carousel responsive to touch?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have the same behaviour in our AoG. In addition the carousel works with voice and touch on a smartphone. Only on a 'real' smart display device it does not work. So far, however, we have not yet found a workaround.

Comment: thanks for your insights! Good to know it's a general issue.